# Mapping dynamic json object from parameter to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate to get a json response body, which looks like this :

```
{
"entities": {
    "Q11649": {
        "type": "item",
        "id": "Q11649",
        "sitelinks": {
            "enwiki": {
                "site": "enwiki",
                "title": "Nirvana (Band)",
                "badges": []
            },
              ..
```

The object "Q11649" is based on a url parameter called ids, for example :
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&props=sitelinks&ids=Q11649

this part at the end **ids=Q11649**

I only want the title value from under enwiki key, however the ids is dynamic so I can't create a POJO to map it to that id.

How can create a dynamic resttemplate method to extract only the title from this json structure?

I have a Wikidata class that looks like this :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Wikidata {

  @JsonProperty("entities")
  private Entity entity;

  public Wikidata () {

  }

  public Wikidata(Entity entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
  }

  public Entity getEntities() {
    return entity;
  }

  public void setEntities(Entity entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
  }

}
```

After reading a few articles, I realise that a map is probably the best way to go, this is how my entity class looks like :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entity {

  @JsonProperty()
  private Map<Object, Object> data;
  
  public Entity () {
    data = new HashMap<>();
  }
  public Map<Object, Object> getData(){
    return data;
  }
  
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void add(String property, String value){
    data.put(property, value);
  }
}
```

My Sitelinks class :

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sitelinks {

  private Enwiki enwiki;

  public Sitelinks () {

  }

  public Sitelinks(Enwiki enwiki) {
    this.enwiki = enwiki;
  }

  public Enwiki getEnwiki() {
    return enwiki;
  }

  public void setEnwiki(Enwiki enwiki) {
    this.enwiki = enwiki;
  }

}
```

And my Enwiki class :

```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Enwiki {
    
      private String title;
    
      public Enwiki () {
    
      }
    
      public Enwiki(String title) {
        this.title = title;
      }
    
      public String getTitle() {
        return title;
      }
    
      public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
      }
}
```

How can I use this map to link between the dynamic id and my sitelinks class so that I can get the title value?

Comment: Check this out : https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Rather than `List<Entity> entities` consider `Map<String, Entity> entities`

Comment: Ok but how do create a dynamic object which changes depending on the url id?